# I need help filling 100 percent of my computer screen's height with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I need help filling up 100 percent of my computer screen's height using Flexbox, while maintaining responsiveness:

My current sign in page via Chrome (Notice the whitespace):

[image]

My current frontend code:

```
const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <RuxContainer className="container">
      <div slot="header" className="header-container">
        <h3 className="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
        <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
        <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
      </div>
      <div className="body-container">
        <form className="rux-form">
          <h2 className="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
          <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
          <div className="sign-in-inputs">
            <rux-input
              id="email"
              placeholder="Email@astro.com"
              label="Email"
              type="email"
              ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"
            ></rux-input>
            <rux-input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"></rux-input>
          </div>
          <div className="sign-in-helper-functions">
            <rux-checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</rux-checkbox>
            <p className="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</p>
          </div>
          <div className="sign-in-container">
            <rux-button className="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
              Sign in
            </rux-button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div slot="footer" className="footer">
        <p>hi</p>
      </div>
    </RuxContainer>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

And, finally, here is my CSS code that uses flexbox:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rux-form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
}

.sign-in-helper-functions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.forgot-password {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #1976d2;
}

.sign-in-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #172635;
}
```

I have tried messing with the main html and body tags but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This can usually be resolved by giving you most parent element with `height: 100vh`

Comment: @TaiweiTuan what if parent elements are not set to 100% height?

Comment: @AfzalK. then you set the parent i.e. `<html>` or `<body>` to `100vh` or `100%`.

Comment: Neither of these options worked for me when implemented @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: can you make a codesandbox or maybe a live version we can check? the problem might be somewhere not on the code you provided as we don't know how you import this SignIn component to your main app

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using the actual frontend code (that is output to the browser, not this backend code that has to be parsed first) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RuxContainer` seems to have a few complicated aspects under the hood. You can either replace it with a `div` or use a `div` to wrap its content:

**Solution 1: Switch from `RuxContainer` to `div`: (not recommended)**

Replacing `RuxContainer` with a `div` accomplishes the desired outcome. Ensure that the .`container` occupies at least the full height of the viewport. Optionally, you can make the `.body-container` take the full remaining space. However, I don't recommend this approach, as using `RuxContainer` might be necessary for the package to work without any problems.

Javascript code:

```
const SignIn = () => {
   return (
   <div className="container"> # Replace 'RuxContainer' with div
      # The content remains the same
   </div>
   );
};
```

CSS code:

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
.body-container{
   flex: 1; /* Allow this section to grow and take up remaining vertical space */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center; /* Center content vertically */
}
```

**Solution 2: Wrap the content of `RuxContainer` with div:**

Wrap the content of `RuxContainer` with a div, and ensure the div occupies the full height of the viewport minus the padding caused by `RuxContainer`. Optionally, wrap `.body-container` with a `div`, allowing it to take the remaining vertical space, and center its content.

JavaScript code:

```
const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <RuxContainer className="container">
      <div className="extend"> # To make it take the full height
        <div slot="header" className="header-container">
          <h3 className="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
          <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
          <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
        </div>
        <div className="extend__body"> # To center the body-container
          <div className="body-container">
            <form className="rux-form">
              <h2 className="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
              <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
              <div className="sign-in-inputs">
                <rux-input
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Email@astro.com"
                  label="Email"
                  type="email"
                  ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"
                />
                <rux-input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"/> 
              </div>
              <div className="sign-in-helper-functions">
                <rux-checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</rux-checkbox>
                <p className="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</p>
              </div>
              <div className="sign-in-container">
                <rux-button className="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
                  Sign in
                </rux-button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div slot="footer" className="footer">
          <p>hi</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </RuxContainer>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

CSS code:

```
.extend {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 2.1rem); /* The padding caused by RuxContainer seems to be 2.1rem. Adjust if needed */
}

.extend__body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Did not work, i noticed in the "inspect" the container seems to increase but the content in the container is not expanding with the container. If that makes sense

Comment: @SupraCoder i edited it, it may work now

Comment: still nothing, the whitespace is still present. Have you tried taking all of the code into a local editor? I am not sure why I cannot get it to work...

Comment: @SupraCoder at my side it worked as expected but i had a typo `min-width: 1000vw` also i realized it is not really needed, so i removed it from the solution, i hope it works now

Comment: yeah i added your changes, and it is still the same. Are you using <RuxContainer> as well? this package is from astrouxds

Comment: For simplicity i used plain html and css, so i replaced it with 'div'. i will try using it in the morning, i hope you find the solution sooner

Comment: it worked when I switched to div instead of RuxContainer! If you edit your answer to include "div" instead of "RuxContainer" ill give you the points! :)

Comment: @SupraCoder Although it might work, I don't recommend it. I updated the solution, i hope it works as expected now

Answer (score 0):

now this will fill up 100% of the computer screen's height, while maintaining responsiveness. You can adjust the flex-grow value on the body-container to change the ratio of the header, body and footer in the container.

```
 body {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This did nothing in filling the screen size...

Comment: @SupraCoder better you give full markup including css u r using

Comment: All the code I have is above

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turning the .container into a flex container allows you to control the height of the content is desirable way. You'll need to add min-width's with this approach, but this approach will stay responsive for any screen size.

I added your code (had to adjust the className's to be class attributes) so that you can see the working solution below in a snippet.

The only change you'd have to make is located in the CSS I implemented.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.header-container {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.body-container {

  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rux-form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
}

.sign-in-helper-functions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.forgot-password {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #1976d2;
}

.sign-in-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer {

  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #172635;
}
```

```html
<RuxContainer class="container">
  <div slot="header" class="header-container">
    <h3 class="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
    <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
    <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
  </div>
  <div class="body-container">
    <form class="rux-form">
      <h2 class="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
      <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
      <div class="sign-in-inputs">
        <rux-input id="email" placeholder="Email@astro.com" label="Email" type="email" ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"></rux-input>
        <rux-input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"></rux-input>
      </div>
      <div class="sign-in-helper-functions">
        <rux-checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</rux-checkbox>
        <p class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sign-in-container">
        <rux-button class="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
          Sign in
        </rux-button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div slot="footer" class="footer">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</RuxContainer>
```